# creating a simple variable in racket

Tags: racket

How could I recreate the code below with a a list that I had declared
as a variable?

```
> (map (lambda (i) (string-append i "!"))
       (list "peanuts" "popcorn" "crackerjack"))

'("peanuts!" "popcorn!" "crackerjack!")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
(define (add-! l)
  (map (lambda (i)
       (string-append i "!")) l))

(define my-list (list "peanuts" "popcorn" "crackerjack"))

(check-expect (add-! my-list)
              '("peanuts!" "popcorn!" "crackerjack!"))
```

Just wrapping your code in a function and calling it on a variable?